# Sharepoint Date compare using Jquery

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, spservices

can anyone let me know whats wrong with following code

```
var day = new Date();
var Today = day.getFullYear() + '-' + (day.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + day.getDate() + ' 00:00:00';
$(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {
    var StDate = ($(this).attr("ows_StartDate"));
    var EnDate = ($(this).attr("ows_EndDate"));
    if (Date.parse(Today) >= Date.parse(StDate) && Date.parse(Today) <= Date.parse(EnDate)) {
        alert("Date is in range")
    }
```

In chrome it works but in IE its give NaN for `Date.parse` method

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue of IE7/8, see for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020658/javascript-json-date-parse-in-ie7-ie8-returns-nan) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182246/javascript-dates-in-ie-nan-firefox-chrome-ok):

> ECMA-262 r3 does not define any date formats. Passing string values to
>   the Date constructor or Date.parse has implementation-dependent
>   outcome. It is best avoided

You could consider the following solutions:

- Use custom [parseISO8601 function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2182529/1375553) or [Date.fromISO function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11021320/1375553) to parse string to a Date object
- Use [momentjs library](http://momentjs.com/) to parse dates in JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

The date format in IE and Chrome differs. Hence it is failing in IE and working in chrome.

You have two options

1. Check the browser version and act accordingly
2. Use jQuery date parsing

   ```
   $.datepicker.parseDate('yy-mm-dd', Today);
   ```